# External and Internal Html table css style conflicts

Tags: css

I have a generic css style defined for table,tr,td in external css file as below -

```
table,tr,td {font: 12px Arial;}
```

I have table inside div having #id and i want to apply different(inline) css style for table,tr,td inside that #id. I'm trying as below -

```
#id table,tr,td{font:11px Arial;}
```

But if i do as above adding inline css for table inside div having #id, outside tables also inheriting the inline css, which i dont want? How i can apply css style only for tables inside div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#id table, #id tr, #id td {
    font:11px Arial;
}
```

Comment: or i guess simply `#id table *` would do just the same